# Fixing and ShortHand Pre-Written Code | C

Tags: c

I'm a new C learner, I saw someone new here asking for a solution to a given C homework

[image]

I tried to solve it but my code looks buggy.

```
int main() {
    int input = 47;
    int first = input%10;
    int second = input/10;

    int diff = first - second;
    if(diff < 0) {diff = diff*-1;}
    int temp = input;

    int count = 0;
    int result[6];

    printf("Input:\n");
    printf("%d\n",input);

    printf("The difference between the digits of 47 is %d. So, D is %d\n",diff,diff);
    while(1)
    {

        temp++;

        first = temp%10;
        second = temp/10;

        int diff2 = first - second;
        if(diff2 < 0) {diff2 = diff2*-1;}

        result[count] = temp;
        printf("The difference between the digits of %d is %d \n",temp,diff2);
        if(diff == diff2)
        {
            printf("The difference between the digits of %d is %d,which is equal to D\n",temp,diff2);
            break;
        }
        ++count;

    }

    int SIZE = (sizeof(result)/sizeof(int)) -1 ;

    printf("Hence the output is ");
    for (int i = 0 ;i < SIZE;i++){

        printf(" %d ",result[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What I'm looking for is how an veteran professional C programmer would do it

Comment: Why do you think your "code looks buggy"? What happens when you build it (with extra warnings enabled)? What happens when you run it? What happens when you use a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code line by line?

Comment: When `diff == diff2` you need to stop the loop *before* you add the number to `result` and print a message for that iteration.

Comment: You don't need to store the output numbers in an array. Print the output number if `diff2 != diff`, and `break` the loop otherwise.

Comment: If you are looking for a review of working code then https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ may be a better fit. Your question is too broad to be on-topic here.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I meant not so optimized code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array is not strictly needed, as you can simply print the numbers as you go.

A helper function to calculate the difference between the digits helps simplify this.

The prompt is rather uninformative, but it would seem the only data to be printed should be the sequence of numbers. It is unclear what should happen when the sequence reaches 100 (in the example below, we stop).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* modify this function to read user input, validate two-digit integer, etc. */
static int get_int(void)
{
    return 47;
}

static int digit_diff(int value)
{
    return abs((value / 10) - (value % 10));
}

int main(void)
{
    int n = get_int();
    const int first_diff = digit_diff(n);

    while (n < 100) {
        printf("%d ", n++);

        if (digit_diff(n) == first_diff)
            break;
    }

    putchar('\n');
}
```

```
47 48 49 50 51
```